# Given an arbitrary infinite set $S$, how to construct an injection $\mathbb{N} \to S$ with the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: functions, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $S$ be an arbitrary infinite set. As a part of our homework, I have the following question:

**Question**: How can I construct an injection $\mathbb{N} \to S$?

Intuitively, I understand that such an injection should exist but describing it explicitly is probably not possible. Therefore, I think we need to use the

**Axiom of Choice**: If $X$ is a set of non-empty sets, then there exists a **choice function** $F$ on $X$, i.e. a function on $X$ such that for all $M \in X$, we have $F(M) \in M$.

Our class was given the following hint: Construct a family of $A_n \subseteq S$ with $|A_n| = 2^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Next, construct a family $B_n \subseteq S$ of non-empty and pairwise disjoint subsets.

However, I do not really know what to do with this hint. Maybe the condition $|A_n| = 2^n$ indicates that we should use the power set of some set with $n$ elements but that is just a vague idea.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me advancing with this problem.

Comment: I think you are expected to deduce the existence of the sets $A_n$ from whatever definition of infinite you have.

Comment: Please include the question you are asking in the body of the question, not just in the title. It is irritating to keep having move up to the title to see what you are actually asking.

Comment: You also need to tell us what definition of "infinite" you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know about that (it's my first question here). Regarding the definition of infinity: It may sound stupid but we call a set infinite if it is not finite. Furthermore, a set $S$ is called finite if there is a non-negative integer $n$ and a bijection from $\{ 1,\dots,n \} \to S$. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you naively argue that an infinite set has an injection from $\Bbb N$ into the set?

Well, pick some $x_0$, then suppose that $\{x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ were chosen, since the set is infinite, there is some $x_n$ which is different from those $n$ elements. So we defined $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, which is clearly the range of an injection from $\Bbb N$ into the set.

Where did we use the axiom of choice? Well, the choice of $x_0$ was arbitrary, but the choice of $x_1$—while arbitrary—depends on the choice of $x_0$, since $x_1\neq x_0$ by design. And the choice of $x_{216}$ depends on the $216$ previous choices. So the choice here is literally in the ability to consolidate the *real* proof that an infinite set has arbitrarily large finite subsets, into a proof that it has a countably infinite subset.

Where did we use choice? We *chose* the $x_n$. So by fixing a choice function, $F$, and applying the recursion theorem to choose $F(n)$ from $X\setminus\operatorname{rng}(F\restriction n)$ we can get our infinite sequence.

---

**Fun exercise.** The above proof relies on the principle of dependent choice, but we can still prove that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset from the weaker "axiom of choice for countable families of sets".

Comment: To understand this a little better, what would be the set of non-empty sets in order to use the Axiom of Choice? Is it $\{ X - \{ x_1,\dots,x_n \} \, | \, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$? (or in other words, what is the domain of your choice function $F$?)

Comment: Yes, but since you don't know what are the $x_n$s a priori, that turns out to be circular. Remember that $x_0=F(X)$ and $x_1=F(X\setminus\{x_0\})$, but you don't know in advance what is $x_0$, so you need to prepare for any emergency. Simply way out: just choose from *all* non-empty subsets; a bit more focused, choose from the co-finite subsets (i.e. those whose complement is finite).

Comment: If we choose $M = \{ T \in P(X) \, | \, X - T \text{ is finite} \}$, then by the Axiom of Choice there is a choice function $F$ on $M$ such that for all $T \in M$, it is $F(T) \in T$. What you do in order to define an injection $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ seems to be this: Choose $f(1) := F(X)$ (well-defined since $X \in M$), and recursively, $f(n) := F(X - \{ f(1), \dots, f(n-1) \})$. But is this a well-defined function? I am not sure if it is allowed to define $f$ like this by making infinitely many deliberate choices.

Comment: Yes, because you are using the recursion theorem, let $G\colon M\to M$ be the function $G(Y)=Y\setminus\{F(Y)\}$, then there is a unique function $g$ such that $g(0)=X$ and $g(n+1)=G(g(n))$, finally, let $x_n=F(g(n))$.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your definition of *infinite* is such that $S$ is infinite if for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an injection $f_n$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into $S$ (or something from which that can easily be inferred). For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $A_n=f_{2^n}\left[\left\{1,\ldots,2^n\right\}\right]$.

- Show that $A_n\setminus\bigcup_{k<n}A_k\ne\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. HINT: What is the largest possible value of $\sum_{k<n}|A_k|$?

Now let $B_n=A_n\setminus\bigcup_{k<n}A_k$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and apply the axiom of choice to $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ to construct an injection from $\Bbb N$ to $S$.